# How to sum some columns in a row

Tags: python, dataframe, sum

I have:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "ID": [55218,55218,55218,55222],
  "Cluster": [0,0,1,1],  
  "Rating":[-1,2,0,2]})
```

I want to sum the Rating of e.g. Cluster "0" for every "ID"

My expected output is:

```py
df_new = pd.DataFrame({
  "ID": [55218,55218,55218,55222], 
  "Cluster": [0,1,1], 
  "Sum": [1,0,2] })
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `groupby`

```
df.groupby("ID")["Cluster"].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: Questions as basic as this one have usually been asked and answered. Please look for duplicates before posting simple, one-line answers.